# x86 thread context switch: Why it's necessary to store program counter into TCB?

Tags: unix, context-switch

I'm trying to understand thread context switch. An abstraction I have right now is one thread will call `yield()`, which is abstracted as:

```
yield() {
  new_thread = schedular.next_thread()
  switch(cur_thread, new_thread)
  house_keeping()
}
```

And `switch(cur_thread, new_thread)` is:

```
switch(cur_thread, new_thread) {
  store all registers into cur_TCB
  load TCB of new_thread
  ret
}
```

It says all registers including `%rip`  will be stored. But if I understand it correctly, after `ret` in `switch` is executed, the `return address` on the new stack will be popped into `%rip`.

So my questions is:  Doesn't this mean the saved `%rip` for the new_thread is not used at all? (Because return address is loaded into it immediately) Why we still need to save %rip during context switch?